# Generate overlay map image from geo data

Tags: google-maps, png, overlay, cluster-computing

I need to generate a transparent image to apply on map similar to these:
[Image_1](https://s3.amazonaws.com/GSTArticles/GoogleMaps/gmaps_art4_1.png)or [Image_2](https://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/2013/07/google_maps_api_overlay_basic.jpg)

I need to generate this image from a dataset: I have many data points (with lat and long) and I would to generate this image (server side) to show density on map of my data.

Know you something (libraries, or best way to solve my problem) about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are **heatmaps**. Google Maps already has this capbility, so you should check out their [sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) and the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer). It can be as basic as loading in your data points and applying them as a layer or you can do much more customization.

Comment: Very well! Is possible to know if there is some ways to export this image overlay also? I need to add this image on iOS Mapkit (Apple Map)